# Why is the trigger wrong in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I spent a lot of time on it, but I still can not resolve it.

For some reasons that I want prevent some same inserting to database. So I choose to use the trigger. That is,

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_card_usage_insert_block 
    BEFORE INSERT ON annual_card_usage_log 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    DECLARE lasttime INT;    -- hold the last insert time

    SELECT
        usage_time INTO lasttime
    FROM
        annual_card_usage_log
    WHERE
        NEW.card_id = card_id
    AND NEW.mch_id = mch_id
    AND NEW.store_id = store_id
    ORDER BY
        usage_time DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    -- only insert when after 300 second
    IF(
        lasttime != NULL
        AND(lasttime + 300 < new.usagetime)
    ) THEN
        INSERT INTO annual_card_usage_log(
            card_id ,
            mch_id ,
            store_id ,
            usage_time
        )
    VALUES
        (
            NEW.card_id ,
            NEW.mch_id ,
            NEW.store_id ,
            NEW.usage_time
        );
    END
    IF;

    END$
```

This is the creating code. And below is the table,

```
CREATE TABLE `annual_card_usage_log` (
      `usage_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
      `card_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `mch_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `store_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `usage_time` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`usage_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sadly I can not create the trigger, it seems wrong. Can you tell me why? Which code is wrong.

I use the mysql client called Sequel Pro, and when I run the sql I got a error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 Execution stopped!" I don't now the reason.

Comment: *can not create the trigger* - why exactly?

Comment: @anatol I use the mysql client called Sequel Pro, and when I run the sql I got a error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
Execution stopped!" I don't now the reason.

Comment: It's useful info, please add to your question

Comment: @anatol thanks. on the way

Comment: And about your issue - it seems like endless loop. You fire your trigger in inserts that fires in trigger

Comment: take a look at this this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504904/insert-into-same-table-trigger-mysql

Comment: @anatol so that means the trigger will run itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137259/discussion-between-blackdog-and-anatol).

Comment: I think you should to do verification before insert, this can solve your problem

Comment: @anatol I don't have the source code, and the bug is cause by one application wrote by others who I can not ask for. So I can not edit the code directly. And I don't has the private key, so I can not redirect the API request. Now the client ask me to fix it. So I only find the trigger can did that.

Comment: take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30556149/4269118

Comment: @anatol is that means with `PROCEDURE` the trigger can do anything including insert a same table? I'm trying the `procedure`

Comment: try changing delimiters

Comment: It means that you won't be able to insert into the same table from a trigger and means that you should find another solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @anatol I solve it. I changed the way. I set the value to a invalid data. Then create a job to delete the invalid data.

Trigger can not insert into a same table because it will cause endless loop, like @anatol point out.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER triger_card_usage_insert_block BEFORE INSERT ON annual_card_usage_log FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    DECLARE lasttime INT(10) ;
    SET lasttime =(
        SELECT
            usage_time
        FROM
            annual_card_usage_log
        WHERE
            NEW.card_id = card_id
        AND NEW.mch_id = mch_id
        AND NEW.store_id = store_id
        ORDER BY
            usage_time DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) ;
    IF (lasttime + 300 > new.usage_time) THEN
    SET new.new_card_id = new.card_id;
    SET new.card_id = 0 ;
    END
    IF ;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```